# Stainless steel type and gauge for pizza oven

Tags: oven

I'm building a stainless steel pizza oven having an inner and an outer dome.

[image: Pizza oven]

I'm going to build it using a type of steel called "304" but my question is regarding the gauge (thickness): I don't want the sheet steel to get bent or deformed because of the high temperature.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Other info you'll want to include, in particular, is what temperature you intend to cook pizzas at.  1000°F?  Lower/higher?  Is this a wood fired oven, gas, charcoal, etc.?

Comment: @JoeM Thanks, yes let me update that. Actually Max 1000F and is going to be wood fire oven. And yes I mean sheet metal gauge sorry.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I build a lot of pizza ovens each year, steel and stainless.
I use 11 to 14 gauge(.120" to .075") in steel and always 16 gauge in stainless 304.

Warping occurs on the front panel where is the door opening, mostly the top part, just and iron angle inside where you doubt it could warp.  If the sheet is rounded or bent, it add strength to it so it never warps at the dome.  Hope it can help.

[image: example oven]

Comment: Hi Dan nice comment, so you use normal steel in the interior and Stainless steel on the outer dome? Thats a good way to go to save money on stainless steel.

Comment: How much insulation do you add bewteen the innner dome and the outer dome Dan?

Answer (score 0):

It is an easy application for any stainless ,so any will be fine. Get a price on ferritics, 405 and 409 are common , They do fine as auto exhaust exposed to 1400 F under some applications.They are 13% chrome compared to the nominal 18 Cr + 8 Ni of 304 types so should be noticeably cheaper. The cost will be more affected by availability which works to the advantage of 304. If a company was going to make thousands of ovens ,they would order 405/409 from the mill. The handicap of the very common 410 SS ( 13 % Cr) is that it is martensitic and any welds will harden and possible crack.Footnote- Most modern major appliances are ferritic stainless although a few are 304 ( non-magnetic).